# Increasing Netbeans Performance

Tags: java, netbeans

Recently  learning on  my  netbeans 8 platform  i  experienced  a  performance  degradation while  working  with  one  of  the  projects , and for  future  use and after a  small  search.
I came  with  below  configuration.Advise  is accepted .

Comment: This is useful to know, but not quite appropriate for this site. It would be more valuble if you explained your answer and made your question clearer.

Comment: this is not a question

Answer (score 1):

Here  is  the  answer:

```
    netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Xmx1600M  -J-XX:PermSize=32m   -J-XX:MaxPermSize=999M  -J-Xverify:none -J-XX:CompileThreshold=100 -J-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true  -J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC  -J-XX:+AggressiveOpts  -J-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis  -J-XX:+TieredCompilation -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled   -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dscala.home=/usr/share/scala-2.11.5 -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"
```